# Automating Alerting on Blocking with Queues and Event Notifications

Tags: sql-server, blocking, event-notification, queue

I need to automate email notifications on blocking on some SQL 2016 servers. I have had a look at running a job through the SQL agent but seems hack n slash. I found an alternative method online that uses queues and event notifications (can't find source again) that seems more suited to the task, however the queue is not populating with entries and am not sure why.

Below is the code I found but it is not working:

```
USE msdb

GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'blocked process threshold', 20
RECONFIGURE
GO

IF exists (select * from sys.services where name like 'BlockedProcessService')
    DROP SERVICE [BlockedProcessService]
GO

IF exists (select * from sys.service_queues where name like 'BlockedProcessQueue')
    DROP QUEUE [dbo].BlockedProcessQueue
GO

CREATE QUEUE BlockedProcessQueue

CREATE SERVICE BlockedProcessService ON QUEUE BlockedProcessQueue ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification])
GO

IF exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'wait_resource_name' and type = 'TF')
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[wait_resource_name]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[wait_resource_name](@obj nvarchar(max))
RETURNS @wait_resource TABLE (
    wait_resource_database_name sysname,
    wait_resource_schema_name sysname,
    wait_resource_object_name sysname
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dbid int
    DECLARE @objid int

    IF @obj IS NULL RETURN
    IF @obj NOT LIKE 'OBJECT: %' RETURN

    SET @obj = SUBSTRING(@obj, 9, LEN(@obj) - 9 + CHARINDEX(':', @obj, 9))

    SET @dbid = LEFT(@obj, CHARINDEX(':', @obj, 1) - 1)
    SET @objid = SUBSTRING(@obj, CHARINDEX(':', @obj, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX(':', @obj, CHARINDEX(':', @obj, 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX(':', @obj, 1) - 1)

    INSERT INTO @wait_resource (wait_resource_database_name, wait_resource_schema_name, wait_resource_object_name)
    SELECT db_name(@dbid), object_schema_name(@objid, @dbid), object_name(@objid, @dbid)

    RETURN
END
GO


use master
go

IF exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'StartBlockedProcessNotification' and type = 'P')
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].StartBlockedProcessNotification
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE StartBlockedProcessNotification
AS
begin

    if exists (select * from sys.server_event_notifications where name = 'BlockedProcessNotification')
    begin
        drop event notification BlockedProcessNotification on server
    end

    CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION BlockedProcessNotification ON SERVER FOR BLOCKED_PROCESS_REPORT TO SERVICE 'BlockedProcessService', 'msdb'
end
GO

EXEC sp_procoption 'StartBlockedProcessNotification', 'startup', 'on'

EXEC StartBlockedProcessNotification

use msdb
go

if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'BlockedProcessActivationProcedure' and type = 'P')
    drop procedure BlockedProcessActivationProcedure
go


CREATE PROCEDURE BlockedProcessActivationProcedure
AS

--Service Broker
DECLARE @message_body xml
DECLARE @message_body_text nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dialog uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @message_type nvarchar(256)

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN --Process the queue
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    RECEIVE TOP (1)
        @message_body = message_body,
        @dialog = conversation_handle,
        @message_type = message_type_name
    FROM BlockedProcessQueue

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Nothing more to process', 0, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN
    END

    IF @message_type = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/EventNotification'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @mail_body nvarchar(max)

        DECLARE @post_time varchar(32)
        DECLARE @duration int
        DECLARE @blocked_spid int
        DECLARE @waitresource nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @waitresource_db nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @waitresource_schema nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @waitresource_name nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocked_hostname nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocked_db nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocked_login nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocked_lasttranstarted nvarchar(32)
        DECLARE @blocked_inputbuf nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @blocking_spid int
        DECLARE @blocking_hostname nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocking_db nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocking_login nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @blocking_lasttranstarted nvarchar(32)
        DECLARE @blocking_inputbuf nvarchar(max)

        declare @notificationSubject varchar(125)

        SET @post_time = CONVERT(varchar(32), @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime'), 109)
        SET @duration = CAST(@message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/Duration)[1]', 'bigint') / 1000000 AS int)
        SET @blocked_spid = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@spid)[1]', 'int')
        SET @waitresource = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@waitresource)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        SET @blocked_hostname = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@hostname)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
        SET @blocked_db = DB_NAME(@message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@currentdb)[1]', 'int'))
        SET @blocked_login = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@loginname)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
        SET @blocked_lasttranstarted = CONVERT(varchar(32), @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/@lasttranstarted)[1]', 'datetime'), 109)
        SET @blocked_inputbuf = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocked-process/process/inputbuf)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        SET @blocking_spid = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/@spid)[1]', 'int')
        SET @blocking_hostname = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/@hostname)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
        SET @blocking_db = DB_NAME(@message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/@currentdb)[1]', 'int'))
        SET @blocking_login = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/@loginname)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
        SET @blocking_lasttranstarted = CONVERT(varchar(32), @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/@lasttranstarted)[1]', 'datetime'), 109)
        SET @blocking_inputbuf = @message_body.value(N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData/blocked-process-report/blocking-process/process/inputbuf)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

        set @notificationSubject = 'MS SQL Server - Blocked Process Report: ' + @@servername

        SELECT
            @waitresource_name = wait_resource_object_name,
            @waitresource_schema = wait_resource_schema_name,
            @waitresource_db = wait_resource_database_name
        FROM master.dbo.wait_resource_name(@waitresource)

        SET @mail_body = 'Posted: ' + ISNULL(@post_time, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Duration: ' + ISNULL(CAST(@duration AS varchar) + ' s', '') + CHAR(10) +
            CHAR(10) +
            '==========Blocked Process==========' + CHAR(10) +
            'SPID: ' + ISNULL(CAST(@blocked_spid AS varchar), '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Wait Resource: ' + ISNULL(ISNULL(QUOTENAME(@waitresource_db) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@waitresource_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@waitresource_name), @waitresource), '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Hostname: ' + ISNULL(@blocked_hostname, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Current Database: ' + ISNULL(@blocked_db, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Login Name: ' + ISNULL(@blocked_login, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Last Transaction Started: ' + ISNULL(@blocked_lasttranstarted, '') + CHAR(10) +
            '----------Input Buffer----------' + CHAR(10) +
            ISNULL(@blocked_inputbuf, '') + CHAR(10) +
            CHAR(10) +
            '==========Blocking Process==========' + CHAR(10) +
            'SPID: ' + ISNULL(CAST(@blocking_spid AS varchar), '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Hostname: ' + ISNULL(@blocking_hostname, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Current Database: ' + ISNULL(@blocking_db, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Login Name: ' + ISNULL(@blocking_login, '') + CHAR(10) +
            'Last Transaction Started: ' + ISNULL(@blocking_lasttranstarted, '') + CHAR(10) +
            '----------Input Buffer----------' + CHAR(10) +
            ISNULL(@blocking_inputbuf, '') + CHAR(10)

        EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MS SQL Server Alerts',  @recipients = 'Mssqlserveralerts <mssqlserveralerts@bayport.co.za>', @subject = @notificationSubject, @body = @mail_body
    END
    ELSE IF @message_type IN ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
    BEGIN

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MS SQL Server Alerts',  @recipients = '<your@alerting.mailbox>', @subject = @notificationSubject, @body = @dialog

        END CONVERSATION @dialog
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END

GO

ALTER QUEUE BlockedProcessQueue WITH ACTIVATION (
    STATUS = ON,
    PROCEDURE_NAME = [BlockedProcessActivationProcedure],
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
)
```

#### Questions

1. What is the cause queue not being populated?
2. Is there better method of altering on blocking than with queues and event notifications?

---

***Reopen Request***
*While the Question and Answer that are linked in the **duplicate** close reason probably do answer the second question, they do not answer the first question: **What is the cause of the above alerting not working?***.

Comment: If you want a meaningful answer you should define what you mean by "not working".

Comment: As indicated in the very first paragraph, "the queue is not populating with entries and am not sure why". For your convenience, there is only one queue, named `BlockedProcessQueue`